# Regular expression validation for URL in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc-3

([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?
I am using the above expression for URL validation. But the problem is when I give only 'www.yahoo' and press the save button I didn't get any error message. Please offer a solution.

Thank you

Comment: here's (somewhat) duplicate post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827557/how-do-you-validate-a-url-with-a-regular-expression-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I guess that post relates more to python. You might find something similar in ASP.NET as well.

But if you want to parse it yourself, you should refer to the [RFC 2396 (URI Generic Syntax)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), which provides the regex and breaks it into components in Appendix B:

> ```
>   ^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
>    12            3  4          5       6  7        8 9
> ```
>
> The numbers in the second line above are only to assist
>   readability;    they indicate the reference points for each
>   subexpression (i.e., each    paired parenthesis).  We refer to the
>   value matched for subexpression     as $.  For example, matching
>   the above expression to
>
> ```
>   http://www.ics.uci.edu/pub/ietf/uri/#Related
> ```
>
> results in the following subexpression matches:
>
> ```
>   $1 = http:
>   $2 = http
>   $3 = //www.ics.uci.edu
>   $4 = www.ics.uci.edu
>   $5 = /pub/ietf/uri/
>   $6 = <undefined>
>   $7 = <undefined>
>   $8 = #Related
>   $9 = Related
> ```
>
> where  indicates that the component is not present, as
>   is    the case for the query component in the above example. 
>   Therefore, we    can determine the value of the four components and
>   fragment as
>
> ```
>   scheme    = $2
>   authority = $4
>   path      = $5
>   query     = $7
>   fragment  = $9
> ```
>
> and, going in the opposite direction, we can recreate a URI reference
>     from its components using the algorithm in step 7 of Section 5.2.

**EDIT**:

After a bit of Googling, I found this in ASP.NET: [`System.Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx), e.g.:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.ics.uci.edu/pub/ietf/uri/#Related");
Console.WriteLine(uri.AbsoluteUri);
Console.WriteLine(uri.Host);
```