# How can I make this regex for a URL more specific?

Tags: regex

I have the following regex that attempts to match URLs:

```
/((http|https):(([A-Za-z0-9$_.+!*(),;/?:@&~=-])|%[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}){2,}(#([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9$_.+!*(),;/?:@&~=%-]*))?([A-Za-z0-9$_+!*();/?:~-]))/g
```

How can I modify this regex to only match URLs of a single domain?

For example, I only want to match URLs that begin with `http://www.google.com`?

This should simplify my regex, but I'm too much of a regex noob to get it working (after all these years...)

Comment: Remember that most RE engines know about `(?:a|b)` (or similar) to match alternatives without generating an unnecessary group. Additionally you could just use `https?` to match both `http` and `https`.

Comment: Nice tip about `https?`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you write that RegEx? I don't know what it's trying to do, but it certainly doesn't match URLs correctly. Here's something it matches:

```
http:@@#9@?~
```

which I'm pretty sure isn't a valid URL.

You shouldn't be using RegEx to match URLs like this. You haven't said what language you're working in, but use whatever its equivalent of [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) is..

Here's a relevant question: [How do you validate a URL with a regular expression in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827557/how-do-you-validate-a-url-with-a-regular-expression-in-python)

Comment: Hi Karl, it's Javascript I'm working in. It's not that I'm validating a URL specifically. Given a chunk of text, I'm trying to find all the URLs I'm interested in (in order to be able to append a string).

Comment: If you're not interested in validating, this will match anything looking like a URL: `https?://(?:www\.)google\.com[^ ]*` for you to append to...