# How to grep for a URL in a file?

Tags: regex, grep

For example, I have a huge HTML file that contains img URL: http://ex.example.com/hIh39j+ud9wr4/Uusfh.jpeg

I want to get this URL, assuming it's the *only* url in the entire file.

```
cat file.html | grep -o 'http://ex[a-zA-Z.-]*/[a-zA-Z.-]*/[a-zA-Z.,-]*'
```

This works **only** if the URL doesn't have the plus signs.

How do I make work for + signs as well?

Comment: Add `+` to the character classes in the brackets.

Comment: Did you try adding the `+` character to your final character set? What happened?

Comment: I added + sign, as well as \+. Neither solution worked.

Comment: Perhaps this is because your URL also contains numeric characters...

Comment: well, I believe that anything that starts with http:// is almost certainly an url. You don't really need to be more specific than that

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you validate a URL with a regular expression in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827557/how-do-you-validate-a-url-with-a-regular-expression-in-python)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You missed the character class `0-9` *(also useless use of cat)*:

```
grep -o 'http://ex[a-zA-Z.-]*/[a-zA-Z0-9+-]*/[a-zA-Z0-9.,-+]*' file.html
```

Slight improvement, use `-i` for case insensitivity and only match images `.jpg` or `.jpeg`.

```
grep -io 'http://ex[a-z.-]*/[a-z0-9+-]*/[a-z0-9.,-+]*[.jpe?g]' file.html
```

Or how about just:

```
grep -io 'http://ex.example.*[.jpe?g]' file.html
```

Comment: There is no need to escape these characters (see my answer). You're right about UUoC, though.

Comment: Grep on my Mac doesn't appear to grog the 1st and 2nd regex. I had to move the hyphen in the last range to the end of the range expression:
`grep -o 'http://ex[a-zA-Z.-]*/[a-zA-Z0-9+-]*/[a-zA-Z0-9.,+-]*' file.html` resp. `grep -io 'http://ex[a-z.-]*/[a-z0-9+-]*/[a-z0-9.,+-]*[.jpe?g]' file.html`

Answer (score 3):

The following fixes your [regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) ***for this specific case*** (including numbers and plus-signs):

```
http://ex[a-zA-Z.-]*/[a-zA-Z0-9.+-]*/[a-zA-Z0-9.+-]*
```

### Demonstration:

```
echo "For example, I have a huge HTML file that contains img URL: http://ex.example.com/hIh39j+ud9wr4/Uusfh.jpeg"
```

I want to get this URL, assuming it's the only url in the entire file.

```
cat file.html | grep -o 'http://ex[a-zA-Z.-]*/[a-zA-Z.-]*/[a-zA-Z.,-]*'
```

This works only if the URL doesn't have the plus signs. How do I make work for + signs as well?

```
cat file.html| grep -o 'http://ex[a-zA-Z.-]*/[a-zA-Z0-9.+-]*/[a-zA-Z0-9.+-]*'
```

output:

```
http://ex.example.com/hIh39j+ud9wr4/Uusfh.jpeg
```

This **does not** extract all valid URLs. There are *plenty* of other answers on this site about URL matching.