# Using regex how to validate url

Tags: php, preg-match

I've simple `form` where `url` should be entered but i would like to use **whatever is better** either `regx` or `anything else` to check if it valid url or not.

I know there are zillion of questions about it already posted, But most of them are very old even before `TLDs` domains and other faild in case of `ftp//` and `https//`

i wish i can get answer that really able to cover such kind of `url` scheme

```
google.com
www.google.com
http//google.com
http//www.google.com
https://google.com
https://www.google.com
ftp://google.com
```

~ Thanks and once again sorry for posting duplicated question but just for getting updated answer as could be possible.

Comment: What about subdomains? Domains like `example.co.uk`? Other protocols? And what is http//www.google.com?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/835527/41967

Comment: Don't use a regex, use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Comment: @Sammitch i've been thinking about using parse_url() can you please submit answer with an example how to use it. ~ thanks

Comment: `filter_var($url,FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)`

Answer (score 3):

**This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The usage for [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) is below, but @wrikken brings up a much better way to simply validate if a URL is 'valid' or not with [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php). `parse_url()` simply parses a specified URL string into its component parts, and will apparently not return a `false` value unless the URL is *catastrophically* broken.

`filter_var()` is sensitive enough that it will detect something minor like an underscore used in a domain name.

```
var_dump(
  filter_var(
    'http://stack-overflow.com/questions/19437105/using-regx-how-to-validate-url?noredirect=1#comment28819663_19437105',
     FILTER_VALIDATE_URL
  )
);

//output: string(113) "http://stack-overflow.com/questions/19437105/using-regx-how-to-validate-url?noredirect=1#comment28819663_19437105"

var_dump(
  filter_var(
    'http://stack_overflow.com/questions/19437105/using-regx-how-to-validate-url?noredirect=1#comment28819663_19437105',
    FILTER_VALIDATE_URL
  )
);

//output: bool(false)
```

`parse_url()` would be better left to extracting portions of a URL that you already know is valid:

```
var_dump(parse_url('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437105/using-regx-how-to-validate-url?noredirect=1#comment28819663_19437105'));
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(17) "stackoverflow.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(50) "/questions/19437105/using-regx-how-to-validate-url"
  ["query"]=>
  string(12) "noredirect=1"
  ["fragment"]=>
  string(24) "comment28819663_19437105"
}
```

Or how about:

Answer (score 0):

Regexes are handy and expensive but for validating URLs:

```
^((ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/|~\/|\/)?([\w]+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z]{1}([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,5}))(:[\d]{1,5})?\/?(\w+\.[\w]{3,4})?((\?\w+=\w+)?(&\w+=\w+)*)?
```