# Validate URL with valid port number and query string

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex, validation

I want to check if a textbox contains a valid URL using regular expression. A valid url can be as follows.

```
http://www.google.com
https://www.google.com
http://clrs.mlslist.com:6103/
http://clrs.mlslist.com:6103/premium/login
http://reso.mlslisting.com/premium/login?rets-version=rets/1.5
```

Can someone help me to frame the validation expression for the ASP RegularExpressionValidator?

Comment: Aside from obviously not using any searches - what did You try?
Regex is not a suitable tool to validate URLs - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827557/how-do-you-validate-a-url-with-a-regular-expression-in-python (You can invent a subset-regex to match a subset of RFC for Your temporary needs, but You'll stuck with improving regex to fit more and more into it over time, which isn't the right approach)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://urlregex.com/:

```
/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+|(?:www\.|[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/\.\w\-_]*)?\??(?:[\-\+=&;%@\.\w_]*)#?(?:[\.\!\/\\\w]*))?)/
```

---

This is a pretty lenient regex that should suit your needs:

```
^https?://[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*\.\w+(:\d+)?(/[\w-=.?]+)*/?$
```

Requires `http://` or `https://`

Requires a set of characters, followed optionally by more sets of characters separated by dots (e.g. `google` or `www.google` or `img1.srv2.google`).

Requires another `.` followed by a set of characters (e.g. `.com`).

Allows optional port (e.g. `:8080`)

From there allows sets of word/number characters and symbols `-=.?` separated by `/`s (e.g. `/premium/login?rets-version=rets/1.5`)

[RegExr Example](http://regexr.com?37can)

Comment: Honestly though, this has been posted to death.

Comment: it is not a good practice to try to use regex for this. You'll get Yourself into long loop of extending (fixing and improving) the regex - once it'll be polished to perfection (and occupy 5 screens of text) - You'll find it quite inefficient ;)

Just few examples: `http://localhost:80/index.html` `http://aa.bb:0/` `http://a._:99999/`- list is endless ;)

Comment: Well it matches the 2nd of those examples, the 3rd is almost certainly an invalid url. `._` can't be a real top level domain. and it only doesn't match a localhost address because I intentionally made it more complex so that it would not. If I was trying to extract URLs from a log file I would use regex as it is a simple solution.

Comment: @OGHaza Thanks. Then suppose I want to make the http or https portion optional, how the expression would change?

Comment: Change `^https?://` to `^(https?://)?`

Comment: @OGHaza how can I make the http or https portion case insensitive? The URL should be valid for Http, HttP, HTTPS, etc.

Comment: Hey Vishnu if you want only the https to be case insensitive you could use something a little strange like: `^[hH][tT][tT][pP][sS]?://` to allow any cases like `HtTpS`. However if you're fine with the whole URL being case insensitive you can use a flag: If your code looks like `string.match(/yourregex/)` you can add an `i` and the last `/` > `string.match(/yourregex/i)`. If your code looks like `re = new RegExp('yourregex')` you can use `i` as the second parameter `re = new RegExp('yourregex', 'i')`

Comment: @OGHaza Noticed an issue. Its allowing multiple ? at a stretch like
http://www.reos.com/upload.aspx??val=1
And its not allowing multiple parameters such as 
upload.aspx?val1=5&val2=7

Comment: The multiple parameter problem can be fixed by adding `&` to the last character class `[\w-=.?&]`. The `?` problem is because this regex doesn't really validate a URL, it just checks for something that looks mostly like a URL <- there are TONS of invalidly formed URLs it'll match. You can try [something like this](http://regexr.com?37guo) but really after this point taking the advice from Vlad's comment is the best idea.

Comment: On the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827557/how-do-you-validate-a-url-with-a-regular-expression-in-python) vlad linked you can see an example of the sort of regex required to accurately validate a URL - it's unbelievably long

Comment: Not valid for 'Https://192.160.96.194:8083' and same patterns

Comment: @KanwarpreetSingh, very true. Something better here https://urlregex.com/

Comment: @OGHaza I resolved the issue in a bit different manner. I already had validations for URL and add one more condition to it.
                                             URL url = new URL(strBaseurl);
                int port = url.getPort();

                if (port > 65535) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.entered_url_not_valid), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

Answer (score 0):

Use a`RegularExpressionValidator` and set the expression to something like this:

> ^([\S\s]{0,4})$

Replace 4 with your desired length (max)

**Example**:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtbx" Runat="server" />

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
        ErrorMessage="Error: RegularExpressionValidator" 
        ValidationExpression="^([\S\s]{0,4})$" 
        ControlToValidate="txtbx" />

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: Not working. The expression is simply validating whatever I type in the textbox.

Comment: @Vinyak all your regex does is check the length. Also it allows line breaks which it definitely should `.{0,4}` would be more suitable, but still unsuitable of course.