# Pandas: filter dataframe per group with condition matching at least one item in group

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe

```
ID   url   session
111   facebook.com   1
111   vk.com   1
111   stackoverflow.com   2
222   wsj.com  3
222   ria.ru   3
222   twitter.com   4
333   wikipedia.org   5
333   rt.com   5
```

I need to get session, if there are a valid urls

```
valid_urls = ['rt.com', 'wsj.com']
```

Desire output

```
ID   url   session
222   wsj.com  3
222   ria.ru   3
333   wikipedia.org   5
333   rt.com   5
```

I know, that I can filter using `df.url.str.contains`, but how can I add there condition with `session`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use transform against each session to find the ones containing at list one valid url, then filter out the dataframe with the resulting boolean series:

```
df[df.groupby('session')['url'].transform(lambda x : x.isin(valid_urls).any())]

    ID            url  session
3  222        wsj.com        3
4  222         ria.ru        3
6  333  wikipedia.org        5
7  333         rt.com        5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
df = df[(df['url'].str.contains('|'.join(valid_url))) & (df.session > 4)]
```

Comment: I want to get all session, there are relevant urls from the list

Comment: then just do print(df["session"]) to get the the session where there is a valid url

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = df[df['url'].isin(valid_urls)]
```

Using your data above and the your valid url list (`valid_urls = ['rt.com', 'wsj.com']`), you can expect the filtered df to be:

```
ID   url   session
222   wsj.com  3
333   rt.com   5
```

If you need to add a second condition with the session, you can use the `|` (OR) or `&` (AND) operator as follows:

```
df = df[(df['url'].isin(valid_urls)) & (df['session'] > 2)]
```

This lets you filter by two conditions, joined either with OR or AND as you need.

EDIT: If you need to generate a list of valid_urls, you can do this step first:

```
from urlparse import urlparse
valid_url = []
all_url = df['url'].tolist()
for url in all_url:
    parse_result = urlparse(url)
    if parse_result.netloc != "":
        valid_url.append(url)
```

Note that this method won't necessarily check the URLs are accessible in a browser though. If you need to verify that you might need to use the `requests` module to make a HTTP call and see what the response code is.

Comment: but my file is bigger. I need a condition to get all urls, where are valid urls.

Comment: @PetrPetrov so it seems to me the real problem is that you need define a list of valid URLs. What you can do is extract a list of all urls by using `all_url = df['url'].tolist()` and then loop through and validate each one by using urlparse (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22238090/validating-urls-in-python). I'll update my answer with an example too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) - first for find all `ids` and `sessions` to new `DataFrame` called `same`. Last [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with inner join. If need check substrings, use `str.contains`:

```
valid_urls = ['rt.com', 'wsj.com']
same = df.loc[df.url.isin(valid_urls), ['ID', 'session']]
#same = df.loc[df.url.str.contains('|'.join(valid_urls)), ['ID', 'session']]
print (same)
    ID  session
3  222        3
7  333        5

print (pd.merge(df, same))
    ID            url  session
0  222        wsj.com        3
1  222         ria.ru        3
2  333  wikipedia.org        5
3  333         rt.com        5
```