# This simply regular expression is really slow, why?

Tags: javascript, regex, performance, hex

I have written this really simple regular expression which checks if the whole string represents one or more hexadecimal numbers (optionally starting with "0x", separated by comma, minus sign or a whitespace character):

```
/^((0x)?[0-9A-F]+[,\-\s]*)+$/i
```

To me, this regex is very straightforward, but this simple test crashs Firefox and Edge at all, Chrome takes 100% CPU usage for about 15 seconds and then returns the expected result "false":

```
/^((0x)?[0-9A-F]+[,\-\s]*)+$/i.test("012345678901234567890123456789_0");
```

Has anyone an idea what's wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this take so long to match? Is it a bug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982466/why-does-this-take-so-long-to-match-is-it-a-bug)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a usual case of a [*catastrophic backtracking*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) (see [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fu3TQd/1)) when a group contains two subpatterns with one of them being optional.

You need to regroup the pattern as

```
/^(?:0x)?[0-9A-F]+(?:[,\s-]+(?:0x)?[0-9A-F]+)*$/i
```

Now, it will match:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:0x)?[0-9A-F]+` - hex number
- `(?:[,\s-]+(?:0x)?[0-9A-F]+)*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `[,\s-]+` - 1+ space, `,` or `-` symbols (remove `+` if only 1 must be matched)
  - `(?:0x)?[0-9A-F]+` - hex number
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cbcei5/1).