# Regex - Python matching between string and first occurence

Tags: python, regex

I'm having a hard time grasping regex no matter how much documentation I read up on. I'm trying to match everything between a a string and the first occurrence of `&` this is what I have

```
link =  "group.do?sys_id=69adb887157e450051e85118b6ff533c&amp;&"
rex = re.compile("group\.do\?sys_id=(.?)&")
sysid = rex.search(link).groups()[0]
```

I'm using https://regex101.com/#python to help me validate my regex and I can kinda get `rex = re.compile("user_group.do?sys_id=(.*)&")` to work but the `.*` is greedy and matches to the last & and im looking to match to the first `&`

I thought `.?` matches zero to 1 time

Comment: your link doesn't have user_group, just group

Comment: `re.compile("user_group\.do\?sys_id=(.*?)&", re.S)`

Comment: sorry that was a typing error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't necessarily need regular expressions here. Use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) instead:

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs 
>>> parse_qs(urlparse(link).query)['sys_id'][0]
'69adb887157e450051e85118b6ff533c'
```

In case of [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) change the import to:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
```

Comment: I've been on here too much, I didn't realize that was part of a url. Nice catch!

Comment: so is urlparse preferred over regex?

Comment: @BrianSmith generally speaking, URLs can be quite complicated and, strictly speaking parsing or validating it with regular expressions can be as hard as [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/835527/771848). In other words, regular expressions is too general of a tool to apply to URL parsing. `urlparse` is specifically designed for that.

Comment: I agree with @alecxe, his solution is much better for this task

Answer (score 2):

You can simply regex out to the `&amp` instead of the final `&` like so:

```
import re
link =  "user_group.do?sys_id=69adb887157e450051e85118b6ff533c&amp;&"
rex = re.compile("user_group\.do\?sys_id=(.*)&amp;&")
sysid = rex.search(link).groups()[0]

print(sysid)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.*
```

is greedy but

```
.*?
```

should not be in regex.

```
.?
```

would only look for any character 0-1 times while

```
.*?
```

will look for it up to the earliest matching occurrence. I hope that explains it.