# What is the best way to make sure a string doesn't contain a link

Tags: python-3.x

What's the best and clean way to make sure a string doesn't contain a link https:// or http:// or even only the address (www.google.com) without http(s) with the built-in libraries

Comment: Not sure exactly what sort of "links" you want to prevent in your string, but check out [How do you validate a URL with a regular expression in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827557/how-do-you-validate-a-url-with-a-regular-expression-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Its enough to write an if statement:

```
str1="https://www.google.com"
keyword="https://"
if keyword in str1:
    print("The chosen string contains a website link")
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be sufficient for quite many examples:

```
str1="https://www.google.com"
str2="http://www.google.com"
str3="www.google.com"
str4="www.google"
str5="http://google"

def check_if_url(inp):
    is_url=False
    if inp.count(".")>=2:
        is_url=True
    return(is_url)

check_if_url(str1)
check_if_url(str2)
check_if_url(str3)
check_if_url(str4)
check_if_url(str5)

>>> True
>>> True
>>> True
>>> False
>>> False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [validators](https://pypi.org/project/validators/) library.

```
>>> import validators
ValidationFailure(func=url, args={'value': '1213', 'public': False})
>>> validators.url("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56086236/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-sure-a-string-doesnt-contain-a-link")
True
>>> validators.url("htt\ps://stackoverflow.com/questions/56086236/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-sure-a-string-doesnt-contain-a-link")
ValidationFailure(func=url, args={'value': 'htt\\ps://stackoverflow.com/questions/56086236/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-sure-a-string-doesnt-contain-a-link', 'public': False})
>>> validators.url("https://stackoverflow/questions/56086236/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-sure-a-string-doesnt-contain-a-link")
ValidationFailure(func=url, args={'value': 'https://stackoverflow/questions/56086236/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-sure-a-string-doesnt-contain-a-link', 'public': False})
```